# motivation for definition of class group by modding out principal ideal group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, dedekind-domain

Given $R$ dedekind domain, it is clear that every ideal $I\subset R$ has $I^{-1}$. Furthermore, any principal ideal is clearly invertible. In $R$, all ideals forms an abelian group G. And principal ideals form a subgroup $H$ of this abelian group G. One define the class group by $G/H$. What is motivation for modding out this $H$? It looks like I am ignoring the blob generated by $(0)$ ideal. I found a pure number theoretical answer ( [Motivation behind the definition of ideal class group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294150/motivation-behind-the-definition-of-ideal-class-group)). Can someone kindly provide a geometrical interpretation?

Comment: I expect this t have been asked on this site a few times already, and answered. Have you looked?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I checked other answers. I only found number theory answers which I do not have a lot intuition on number theory. Was there a good reference one can use as self study to work out problems on computation of class groups?

Comment: I think you have several imprecise statements, which may (or may not) be contributing to your confusion. 1) The zero ideal $(0)$ has no inverse. 2) The set of ideals of $R$ does not form a group, only a monoid.  Actually not even that, because we again need to exclude the zero ideal so that $R$ is the multiplicative identity.  Anyway, the set of *nonzero* [fractional ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal#Definition_and_basic_results) is a group under multiplication.

Comment: For a more geometric approach, you might start by reading about [divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)) and the [Picard group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_group).

Comment: @Quasicoherent Yep. Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, a fractional ideal of a domain $R$ is a line bundle $L$ on $X=\operatorname{Spec}X$ together with a fixed embedding $L\to\mathcal K_X$ into the sheaf of rational functions on $X$. Modding out the principal ideals is the same, under this correspondence, to forgetting the embedding into $\mathcal K_X$

Answer (score 1):

Since a Dedekind domain is a UFD iff it is a PID, the class group measures how much unique factorization fails in $R$ by measuring how far the ideals are from being principal.