# Why do we use *fractional* ideals in construction of the class group?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, ideal-class-group

I am trying to give a simplified explanation of the class group to students at the upper undergraduate level, who likely have a basic understanding of ring and group theory. While my motivation for constructing the class group as the quotient of the ideal group by the principal ideal group seems clear, I am struggling to justify the extension to *fractional* ideals. What necessitates this? In the example of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, we can show that the product of any two non-principal ideals is principal, which holds with the class group being $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. What is the problem with regular ideals that necessitates the shift to fractional ideals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing necessitates the use of fractional ideals, you can define the ideal class group perfectly well without them, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/296094/31917 . It is maybe just slightly neater / mathematically more convenient to quotient a group by an obvious subgroup than to use the equivalence relation mentioned there, but the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

An integral domain $A$ is a Dedekind ring if and only if the set of *fractional ideals* forms an abelian group under ideal multiplication. Since we want to assign the class number to any Dedekind ring, it seems very natural to consider the group of fractional ideals.